# How to display file browser from click on text and have mouse cursor change to pointer when hovering text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, uploadify

I'm trying to display a file chooser when a user clicks a link on my page. I've looked around a bit, but still haven't found a complete solution.

I have ruled out binding a listener to the click event on my link and simulating the click event on my form's file field because I've read that Safari doesn't support programmatically clicking on an input[type=file].

Currently I am using the approach where I set the opacity of the file field to 0 and absolute position it over the top of the link, effectively intercepting any clicks on the link. The problem with this is that I can't figure out a way to change the user's cursor when they hover the link since it is obscured by the file input, which doesn't allow for such styling. I have given all immediate parent elements the css style cursor: pointer, but still no luck.

Does anyone have an idea of a different approach I could take in order to get the cursor to change to a pointer on hover of my link? Is my best bet going to be going with something like they have at http://www.uploadify.com/?

**EDIT**

To explain a little better, I have this file input on my page:

```
<div class="logo_file">
    <input id="logo_file_field" type="file">
</div>
```

With this css:

```
.logo_file {
    position: absolute;  /* this element's parent has position: relative */
    top: -65px;
    left: 0;
    width: 175px;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
}
input#logo_file_field {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

And I am trying to show the file chooser corresponding to that field when the user clicks this link:

```
<div class="logo_link_wrap">
    <a id="logo_change_link">Change Photo</a>
</div>
```

Which has this css:

```
.logo_link_wrap {
    margin-top: 38px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Right now I am placing the invisible file field over the link, but the cursor is not turning into a pointer like it should when you hover over a link. The file chooser does display, it's really only the cursor not changing that is holding me up. Thanks

Comment: You need to share some example with us because its very hard to understand what you are trying to achieve. You are trying to display a upload field(input type=file) when someone clicks on an link on you page? How are you displaying the field and where is it located? It very hard to debug this problem for you because we have nothing to look at. This does not sound like a big problem because cursor styling is very simple, I just don't know where the problem unless I have some code from you to argue with.

Comment: Thanks. Yea, cursor styling is simple, but not so much for the file input. :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are placing the input field over the link and making the input field invisible by using `opacity:0;`. But the input field is still there and is blocking the cursor access to the link.
Would it not be better to replace the opacity with `display:none`?

With `display:none` you hide the input field and remove it from the flow. I'm assuming that you want the link to be used to active the upload function of the input field, and I'm also assuming that you know how to do that.

Comment: I was able to get it working based on the link I posted in a comment to @shrishaster. I believe that if I were to hide file input via dispaly: none, that it will no longer respond to browser events. Also, I changed it so that the text is no longer a link, I just needed it to appear like a link. I would have loved to have been able to use the link click to fire off an event on the file field element, sadly this isn't supported in all browsers.

Answer (score -1):

Try wrapping the input tag in an anchor tag

```
<a href="#"><input type="file" ... /></a>
```

Comment: This would work, but then it would also add the other qualities of a link, ie text-colour, underline, etc.
CSS is a better solution

Comment: CSS can still be used to remove other qualities of the link save the pointer

Comment: Yeah but adding one quality is easier and cleaner then removing more than one.
But anyway, I re-read the question and updated my answer to actually work for what he needs.

Comment: This is a very bad hack, even though I'm not sure what the problem is to begun with, I'm very sure this is not a good solution to that problem. Input element are not suppose to be nested with in a anchor

Comment: @Chibuzo Nesting input elements within a anchor tag is invalid code. These are to different types of user inputs. The anchor is to get the user to navigate the page, move to another page ore a website. The input field is to get the user to interact with the site by giving it his values. They are not meant to be mixed together and can screw up the pages compatibility.

Comment: I did try this, but the anchor wrapping the file field catches the click event, and not the file field.